# perl: can't get the global var before the place that var is defined

Tags: perl, variables, scope

for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

main();

my %h = (
    name => 'abc',
    value => '123',
);

sub main {
    print "Dumping the hash...\n";
    print Dumper(%h);
}

1;
```

the result is:

```
Dumping the hash...
```

So perl can call main before it be implemented, why it doesn't know the global var %h which even define early than main()?

Comment: It does know about `%h`, it's just empty. https://eval.in/268769

Comment: yes, I know I can move main() after %h, then it can work, I'm just wondering is there any doc explain why and how perl act in this way.

Comment: Technically `%h` is in the scope of `main()` just empty, but with allocated hash memory (`HASH(0x8fa3370)` in example above)

Comment: The very first line in perlsyn: "A Perl program consists of a sequence of declarations and statements which run from the top to the bottom."

Comment: It does what you ask it to, in order. Which is first: Run main. 
Second: Populate `%h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two phases of processing of every Perl program: the compilation phase and the run phase. During the compilation phase, `my` and `sub` are processed, so Perl now knows you'll be using the globally accessible lexical variable `%h`. It's not populated, though - that would happen during the run phase. But, `main` is called before `%h` is populated.

Answer (score 2):

The `my` and the `=` are unrelated. In CS jargon, `%h` is actually defined before `main` is called (`my`). You're asking why the assignment wasn't performed (`=`).

`main()` is executed before the assignment to `%h` because `main()` is found before the assignment to `%h` in the code.

It's exactly the same reason that

```
print("abc\n");
print("def\n");
```

will never print

```
def
abc
```